# Поиск максимальной пропускной способности сети

Tags: php

Столкнулся с очень интересной задачей. Нужно подсчитать максимальную пропускную способность сети используя php. Кто нибудь сталкивался возможно с подобными задачами. Как вы реализовывали и через что ?

[image: Вот пример того как выглядит задача на пропускную способность сети]

Если есть какие нибудь идеи на php или модули то посоветуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: Классическая задача максимального потока. Берите любой описанный алгоритм и реализуйте его.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class getMaximumFromPath {

    static $points = [
        '1' => ['3' => 8.4, '2' => 7.1, '4' => 5.3],
        '2' => ['5' => 9.1],
        '3' => ['6' => 8.2, '5' => 4.2],
        '4' => ['6' => 7.3],
        '5' => ['6' => 6.3],
    ];

    public static $startPointId = 1;
    public static $endPointId = 6;

    static function getSum($summ, $parentPointId, $pathPointId) {

        $summResult = [];

        foreach(self::$points[$parentPointId] as $key => $value) {

            if ($parentPointId == self::$startPointId) { $summ = 0; $pathPointId = self::$startPointId; }

            $summ = $summ + $value;
            $pointId = $key;
            $pathPointId = $pathPointId . "," . $pointId;

            if ($pointId != self::$endPointId) {
                $summResult = array_merge(
                    $summResult,
                    self::getSum($summ, $pointId, $pathPointId));
            } else {
                $summResult[] = [$summ, $pathPointId];
                $summ = $summ - $value;

                $pathPointId = explode(',', $pathPointId);
                unset($pathPointId[count($pathPointId) - 1]);
                $pathPointId = implode(',', $pathPointId);
            }
        }

        return $summResult;

    }
}

function usersort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[0] == $b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[0] > $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

$getMax = getMaximumFromPath::getSum(0, getMaximumFromPath::$startPointId, getMaximumFromPath::$startPointId);
usort($getMax, 'usersort');
var_dump($getMax);

echo "Maximum path it is = " . $getMax[0][1] . "  with score: " . $getMax[0][0]  ;

?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in Z:\home\localhost\www\saipis\do_work.php on line 5